# Deleting file with specific condition having dates in file name in linux

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I need to to delete all files from a folder with below mentioned condition.

File Name pattern: `fileNameBeginDateEndDate.txt` (begin and end date in YYYYMMDD format)

All files in which current date is not in between the begin date and end date need to be deleted.

Example, if today's date is 2018-01-16,

- File that need to be deleted: `File2016010120170101.txt`
- File that should not be deleted: `File2016010120190101.txt`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - What did you try, and why didn't it work out? Also, please take the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [ask] first.

Answer (score 0):

This filter will only output filenames matching your criteria, that is those that needs to be deleted:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ne 'BEGIN { $now=localtime->ymd("")} ($s,$e)=($_=~m/(\d{8})(\d{8})\./); print $_ if $e lt $now || $s gt $now'
```

Examples:

```
 echo "File2016010120170101.txt" | perl -MTime::Piece -ne 'BEGIN { $now=localtime->ymd("")} ($s,$e)=($_=~m/(\d{8})(\d{8})\./); print $_ if $e lt $now || $s gt $now'
 File2016010120170101.txt
 echo "File2016010120190101.txt" | perl -MTime::Piece -ne 'BEGIN { $now=localtime->ymd("")} ($s,$e)=($_=~m/(\d{8})(\d{8})\./); print $_ if $e lt $now || $s gt $now'
 (nothing)
```

Depending on how you have your initial list of filenames, you can preprocess the list and then just run `xargs rm` on the result.

I would advise on adapting the regex to be as strict as possible depending on your files. And/Or to review the files about to be deleted before really deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/File[0-9]{16}\.txt" -exec \
bash -c 'd=$0; f="$1"; [[ $f =~ File([0-9]{8})([0-9]{8})\.txt ]]; 
         [[ "$d" -lt "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || "$d" -gt "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ]] && rm "$f"' \
         $(date +"%Y%m%d") {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o  extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
now=${(%):-%D{%Y%m%d}}
rm ./*[0-9](#c16).txt(e'{! ((now >= REPLY[-20,-13] && now <= REPLY[-12,-5] ))}'))
```

- `(%)` parameter expansion flag that turns on prompt expansion for the expansion of the parameter.
- `${:-value}`: form of Bourne-like `${var:-value}` expansion without `var`, so it expands to the given `value`.
- `%D{%Y%m%d}`: prompt expansion to expand to today's date in that format. Another approach would have been to use `zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime -s now %Y%m%d $EPOCHSECONDS` or use the system's `date` command: `now=$(date +%Y%m%d)`.
- `(#c16)` extendedglob operator to match 16 of the previous atom (similar to ksh93's `{16}([0-9])`).
- `(e:code:)`: glob qualifier to select files based on the evaluation of the code.
- `REPLY[-20,-13]`: 20th last to 13th last characters of `$REPLY` (that holds the path of the file being examined).